# Convert DoubleBinding value to IntegerBinding

Tags: binding, javafx, double, javafx-8

I have the following Problem.
I want to concat a String with an DoubleBinding to an String property.

```
Slider slider = new Slider(1, 5000, 500);
Label sliderValue = new Label();
sliderValue.textProperty().bind(Bindings.concat("Sleep: ", slider.valueProperty()));
```

This is working fine.

But I don't want to display the Double Binding as an Double, I want to round it to an int.

As you can see in the screenshot the Number is added as an Double to String.

[image]

Is there any way to do that, without creating an Listener?

Sry if my english it not correct. :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Bindings.format](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/binding/Bindings.html#format-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-) instead:

```
sliderValue.textProperty().bind(
  Bindings.format("Sleep: %.0f", slider.valueProperty())
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can cast `double` to `int`:

```
sliderValue.textProperty().bind( Bindings.concat( "Sleep: ", 
   Bindings.createIntegerBinding( () -> (int) slider.valueProperty().get(), slider.valueProperty()) ) );
```

Comment: This solution is nice too.
But i like the one with the Bindings.format more. Thank you anyway